# Update individual form field with js

Tags: javascript, input, refresh

I have a function I'd like to add inside <script> tags, and would like to have it updated dynamically every second in an input field without erasing the data in the other fields. Below is an example of the code that I am using:

```
 function genID() {
  $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);;
  $characters = "0123456789";

  return $milliseconds;
 }

<form id="myform" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="identifier" onload="genID()">
  <input type="text" id="userdata">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm sure I need javascript to update that specific field value, but not sure how to refresh individual elements and retrieve a new value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I have a function I'd like to add in tags" Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish? I cannot make sense of that sentence.

Comment: Sorry I had meant in script tags, but must have made a typo. I mean a function I'd like to place on the same page as my form.

Comment: No you just have to encode the angle brackets...  As for your question, it is too broad: you need to learn how to generate random IDs, use setInterval or setTimeout, modify the DOM...

Comment: Well, my function calls an id I'm satisfied with,, but only when the page is reloaded. Do you know how to reload a single input field?